# Using requirejs with ArcGIS API for JavaScript v 4 API from CDN?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

ArcGIS API for JavaScript Quick Start guides show "all-in-a-single-html" approach which is good for examples. However how about bigger apps?

I added comment on older issue (closed) at https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/issues/32.

That works on 4.0, but I have requirejs import errors with the latest version today - 4.12:

```
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/Promise", needed by: esri/views/MapView
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/AbortController", needed by: esri/core/promiseUtils
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/array", needed by: esri/PopupTemplate
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/Set", needed by: esri/PopupTemplate
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/Map", needed by: esri/core/Evented
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/global", needed by: esri/request
Script error for "@dojo/framework/shim/WeakMap", needed by: esri/intl/date, esri/intl/number
Script error for "maquette", needed by: esri/views/overlay/ViewOverlay
Script error for "maquette-css-transitions", needed by: esri/widgets/support/widgetUtils
Script error for "maquette-jsx", needed by: esri/widgets/support/jsxFactory
```

I mean these require.config paths work on 4.0, but do not work on 4.12

```
paths: {
      'esri': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri',
      'dojo': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojo',
      'dojox': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/dojox',
      'dijit': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/dijit',
      'moment': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0' // To resolve Script error for "moment/moment", needed by: esri/plugins/moment
    }
```

Repo with sample files for both version is at https://github.com/r-pankevicius/arcgis-js-api-with-requirejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the issues are in your error. You're missing the requirejs configs for the `@dojo` and `maquette` modules. You can get an idea of what these might look like by looking at how we set up workers to load from the CDN in webpack builds like in [this demo](https://github.com/odoe/jsapi-vue-template/blob/master/src/worker-config.ts)

Here is what a requirejs config would look like.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'esri': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/esri',
        'dojo': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/dojo',
        'dojox': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/dojox',
        'dijit': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/dijit',
        '@dojo': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/@dojo',
        'cldrjs': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/cldrjs/dist/cldr',
        'globalize': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/cldrjs/dist/globalize/dist/globalize',
        'maquette': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/maquette/dist/maquette.umd',
        'maquette-css-transitions': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/maquette-css-transitions/dist/maquette-css-transitions.umd',
        'maquette-jsx': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/maquette-jsx/dist/maquette-jsx.umd',
        'moment': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/moment',
        'tslib': 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/tslib/tslib',
    }
});
```

You can find a working demo [here](https://jsbin.com/vicakijibu/1/edit?js,output).

It's still very slow though, because requirejs will not take advantage of the built layer files in the CDN.